# Calculate distance from TangoPoseData

Tags: java, google-project-tango

My Project Tango device has recorded two Java [TangoPoseData](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/java/TangoPoseData) observations. How can I calculate distance, in meters, between those two observations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Coordinate Pair Frames Documentation](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/overview/frames-of-reference):

> For all coordinate frame pairs, the unit of measurement is meters.

Also...

> Project Tango uses a right-handed, local-level frame for the START_OF_SERVICE and AREA_DESCRIPTION coordinate frames. This convention sets the Z-axis aligned with gravity, with Z+ pointed upwards, and the X-Y plane is perpendicular to gravity that is locally level with the ground plane.

So the coordinates can be used with standard libraries like [JTS Topology Suite](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html) for coordinates using **START_OF_SERVICE and AREA_DESCRIPTION coordinate frames**.

```
public static Coordinate coordinate(TangoPoseData pose){

    return new Coordinate(pose.translation[TangoPoseData.INDEX_TRANSLATION_X],
                pose.translation[TangoPoseData.INDEX_TRANSLATION_Y],
                pose.translation[TangoPoseData.INDEX_TRANSLATION_Z]);
}
```

Coordinates provide a [distance method](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Coordinate.html#distance(com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate)):

```
double distanceInMeters = coordinate(pose1).distance(coordinate(pose2));
```